# Getting Error "{"errorMessages":["There was an error parsing JSON. Check that your request body is valid."]}

Tags: curl, json

```
curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://bankofloyal.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue' \
          --user aditya.singh@lji.io:$JIRA_TOKEN \
          --header 'Accept: application/json' \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --data '{
            "fields": {
              "project": {
                "key": "'$JIRA_PROJECT'"
              },
              "parent": {
                "key": "'$PARENT_ISSUE_KEY'"
              },
              "components": [
                {
                  "id": "'$COMPONENT_ID'"
                }
              ],
              "summary": "Directories with migration changes: '"${DIR_JOINED}"'",
              "description": "Name of models: '"${MODEL_NAMES}"'",
              "issuetype": {
                "name": "Sub-task"
              }
            }
          }'
```

I wanted a ticket generated using the cURL but getting "JSON Parse error". While debugging, I found the problem is in the summary and description of the body, wrongly using the variables `DIR_CHANGED` and `MODEL_NAME`. Can you suggest some other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing the actual contents of your shell variables, I assume at least one contains a literal newline, tab, double quote, or possibly some other character that needs to be encoded in JSON documents.  In general, avoid injecting shell strings into JSON. Use `jq` to create valid JSON from shell variables.  This ensures that the strings are properly encoded.

In the script fragment below, I assume the five shell variables used with `jq`  have already been set to their intended values.  The script then creates a JSON document by giving the shell variables to `jq` to insert at the appropriate places in the provided "template" as JSON-encoded strings.  This result is assigned to the `payload` shell variable, which is later used with `curl` as the option argument of the `--data` option.

```bash
payload=$(
        jq -n -c \
                --arg project_key "$JIRA_PROJECT" \
                --arg parent_key "$PARENT_ISSUE_KEY" \
                --arg components_id "$COMPONENT_ID" \
                --arg dirs "$DIR_JOINED" \
                --arg models "$MODEL_NAMES" '
        {
                fields: {
                        project: { key: $project_key },
                        parent: { key: $parent_key },
                        components: [{ id: $components_id }],
                        summary: ("Directories with migration changes: " + $dirs),
                        description: ("Name of models: " + $models),
                        issuetype: { name: "Sub-task" }
                }
        }'
)

curl --request POST \
          --user "aditya.singh@lji.io:$JIRA_TOKEN" \
          --header 'Accept: application/json' \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --data "$payload" \
          'https://bankofloyal.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue'
```

Note that the variables, like `$dirs` and `$project_key`, used within the `jq` expression, *are `jq` variables*, not shell variables.  These get their values from the `--arg` option on the `jq` command line.

The parenthesised expressions that are the values of the `summary` and `description` keys are parenthesised because they are expressions that need to be evaluated to get at their final values.

If you need to create `jq` variables containing data that aren't strings, for example, if you need to insert booleans, numbers, or JSON document fragments, then use `--argjson` in place of `--arg` (i.e. `jq ... --argjson components_id "$COMPONENT_ID" ...` if the component's ID is supposed to be a number rather than a string).

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment. (Edit: I will get down voted to invisibility it seems, please give some **recommendations to straighten myself up** then. ) (This was never meant to farm upvotes, **please consider this a comment and go upvote the answer up there instead.**)

First things first. Please syntax highlight unless code block is trivial (short, not quote intensive, etc.) See: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). I wrote ```` ```shell ````, rather than ```` ``` ```` to start code block below. It is all green due to variables being green as well, that doesn't help much.

I updated first few variable expansions for consistency.

This looks good, it was not an expansion issue to begin with.

```bash
curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://bankofloyal.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue' \
          --user "aditya.singh@lji.io:${JIRA_TOKEN}" \
          --header 'Accept: application/json' \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --data '{
            "fields": {
              "project": {
                "key": "'"${JIRA_PROJECT}"'"
              },
              "parent": {
                "key": "'"${PARENT_ISSUE_KEY}"'"
              },
              "components": [
                {
                  "id": "'"${COMPONENT_ID}"'"
                }
              ],
              "summary": "Directories with migration changes: '"${DIR_JOINED}"'",
              "description": "Name of models: '"${MODEL_NAMES}"'",
              "issuetype": {
                "name": "Sub-task"
              }
            }
          }'
```

If you want to make sure, run an `echo` of quoted data block. Better yet pipe it to `jq`, that should give a pretty JSON output.

```bash
echo '
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "'"${JIRA_PROJECT}"'"
        },
        "parent": {
            "key": "'"${PARENT_ISSUE_KEY}"'"
        },
        "components": [
            {
                "id": "'"${COMPONENT_ID}"'"
            }
        ],
        "summary": "Directories with migration changes: '"${DIR_JOINED}"'",
        "description": "Name of models: '"${MODEL_NAMES}"'",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Sub-task"
        }
    }
}' | jq
```

It might be better to dive into [Jira Rest Api Exaples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) or ask on StackOverflow, as issue is not a BASH nor a Linux issue. I checked your flags, they match what is on Atlassian's site, although with their long forms.

#### Addendum:

I had evaluated my strictly-quoted version of the command, so @Kusalananda is right on that there indeed could be a quotation error due to white space or special characters.

However, this error message is the response from the Atlassian server, curl did work properly. Better to use the quoted version though.

<s>lso one [Atlassian Community thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Getting-error-There-was-an-error-parsing-JSON-Check-that-your/qaq-p/1811429) suggests that **it could be the `@` in the username**.</s>

#### Yet Another Addendum

curl would always work anyway, so long as credentials and api resource were correct. It must have been a new line or similar that pre-terminated the data block. Thus the error in the title. @Kusalananda was on point.

Comment: 1/2 Technically it should be a comment. Personally, with a "_this is too long for a comment_" I'd have let it ride, but I'm only one member of the community. Suggestions? Your "_First things first_" is ideal for a comment. Subsequent rewritten block probably not relevant for a comment. You could shorten the next `echo` block with something like "_Use `echo` to check what you're feeding to `curl`. For example, `echo '{ your json expression ... }'` or even better, `echo '{ your json expression ... }' | jq`._"

Comment: 2/2 The "_It might be better..._" seems fine for a comment. As does the addendum. Good luck. Hope you don't get too many -1s because what you've written is helpful - although it isn't really an answer is it

Comment: Those are valid points and actual suggestions which I will follow going forward. About echo part, I am a fond of ability to copy-paste; a link to some proper question/answer should tick that box though. Thanks Sir.